# Is it possible to mount very small PC-like computers on an electric socket?

Tags: power-supply, mount, raspberry-pi, case, form-factor

I've been thinking of getting something like Raspberry Pi (or similar small computer) to use as a print server, but am irked by the prospect of having to find a shelf for it near the electric socket and have a cable dangle to to reach it. Then I got to thinking: Can't the computer just live on top of the socket? Weak computers these days are pretty small. Even with an AC-to-DC converter, it's not inconceivable to make one light and small enough to stably be mounted onto a socket.

Is this something realistic? Does such hardware exist? And if so - are these mounting adapters for non-socket-mounted computers, or perhaps computers pre-engineered so that their power converters and case are designed from the get-go to fit a power socket?

Comment: Like a PwnPlug?

Comment: @grawity: What's that?

Answer (score 1):

Chip PC make Jack PC which fit inside a socket housing:

http://portal.chippc.com/thin-clients/jack-pc/thin-client.asp?p=jack-pc-6800

Power is POE or external.

You can also get USB power supplies in a socket which might power a Raspi, eg

https://www.electricaldirect.co.uk/product/bg-13a-2-gang-switched-socket-with-2xusb-31a-white-947556

and shelves with attached over sockets to provide a support, eg

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-GANG-Mobile-Phone-Tablet-CHARGER-SHELF-ONLY/132726810346

There are ready-done ideas here:

https://www.instructables.com/id/Inexpensive-Wall-Mounting-for-Headless-Raspberry-P/

https://www.min.at/prinz/?entry=entry150323-165443

Compliance with mains electrical regulations may vary according to your location and whether this is for your home or a workplace.

Edit to add:

The Chip JackPC fits into a standard wall back box, with the network connection/POE internally on IDC connectors.

In most commercially-available parts you will end up with a 'power dangle' as manufacturers are reluctant to put mains electricity in the same box as a Rasp Pi. The main alternative is POE and a POE HAT.

Another project for inspiration is here:

> a home server, powered by raspberry Pi, in an interesting form factor
>   - squeezed into a room thermostat enclosure, with WiFi, a colour touchscreen, a few other bells and whistles, **wired direct to mains for
>   24/7 operation** and installed into a standard wall backplate.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=81646

That is using a Pi model A. It appears he used the thermostat's internal power supply and adjusted the Pi to run down to 3.3 volts reducing current demand and improving regulation.

http://labs.domipheus.com/blog/pi-on-the-wall-wall-mounted-home-server-part-1-introduction/

Comment: So, the JackPC is neat-looking, but it  seems it doesn't plug into an electric socket but an Ethernet socket (with a large hole). The on-plate tape-mounted Raspberry Pi is a neat idea, but not quite what I asked for. The min.at site might just do it - need to read further. Anyway, +1 for effort!